# Static initialization, main and premain order of execution

Tags: java, static, initialization

Let's say that I have the following project structure:

Inst.java

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

final public class Inst {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long sizeof(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
    public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 10;
}
```

SomeClass.java

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int myVar;

    public SomeClass(final int myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }

    public static class StaticClass {
        private static final int SOME_VAR = 1;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int init = Constants.MAX_LENGTH;
        SomeClass clazz = new SomeClass(init);           
    }
}
```

The Oracle Docs state the following:

> After the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has initialized, each premain method will be called in the order the agents were specified, then the real application main method will be called.

To my mind, this implies that the `premain` Method is called *immediately* after the JVM is initialized, and hence `Inst` is initialized first (in this example).

Additionally, `static` is initialized (as far as I know) upon class-loading, or more generally upon the first reference of a class.

So this means that, in this example, initialization and execution order is as follows:

1. `premain()` is called after JVM is initialized
2. `main()` is called as the entrypoint of the application
3. `Constants.MAX_LENGTH` is initialized (referenced in main)
4. `StaticClass` is initialized (due to an instance of the outer class being created)
5. An instance of `SomeClass` is created

Is my ordering above correct?

Comment: Could you please specify to which point your comment pertains? I would imagine it pertains to `1`, but I'm not sure what you mean by it. I am interested in the order of execution and that point at which initialization occurs.

Comment: BTW: I intentionally excluded static initializer blocks (i.e. `static { ... }`) inside the classes as, AFAIK, they would be executed in the order they are encountered similar to `static` variables. Am I wrong?

Comment: First: Constants.MAX_LENGTH is a constant expression, [which doesn't load the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

Comment: Your code won't be compiled as `Constants.MAX_LENGTH` is `private` but you are trying to access it in class `Main`. Another problem is that it is `long` but you are trying to assign it to an `int`. Also, the constructor of `SomeClass` should accept `long`.

Comment: Sorry. Your question is unclear. Are you writing "Java programming language agents" or are you writing a regular Java program? How are you running the code in the question?

Comment: Second: Inner class is not accessed in a way described by the JLS §12.4.1, so it is not initialized.

Comment: Third: You can add a `static {System.out.println("Foo is initialized"); }` to your classes to see when they are loaded.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Oops! That was a mistake on my part. It should be `public`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The question pertains to general initialization order, I am not writing an agent at all. Let's say that the class is run by packaging both the `Inst` class and the rest of the classes in separate jar files and running `java -javaagent:inst.jar -jar main.jar`. Does that help?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn re: First : Does `A static field declared by T is assigned.` not match despite that, though? Or is this simply a case of the compiler optimizing the initialization away? re: Second: So only `new SomeClass.InnerStaticClass()` would initialize it? re: Third: I was wondering if there was a specific JLS section that would explain this ordering in a more deterministic way. Is `§12.4.1` what I'm looking for, then?

Comment: 'Static inner' and `InnerStatic` are both contradictions in terms. This is a static class, not an inner class.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I apologize, you are correct. An inner class may not be `static`. I have updated the question.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the `Constants.MAX_LENGTH` as written in the code is not final, so it is not a constant, even though it is all caps.

Comment: Who names a class `Constants`, with a `public` field in all caps, and doesn't put a `final` modifier on it? Thanks @hidralisk, I did miss that. Shows how important following conventions is.

Comment: I typed all this down rather quickly before having to go to sleep. It was indeed my intention to have it be `public static final`.

Comment: I have edited the question to inquire only regarding the ordering itself, as I feel that the other questions I had were already answered through the various comments. I feel that the existing answer already covers it quite well, but I'll hold on with accepting just in case additional input comes in.

Comment: Unsure why the close votes remained after I already edited the question, but I will be accepting the existing answer as no additional input was received. Thanks to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the static initializers are called immediately after the class is loaded. But classes are loaded before these are needed. So, before `main()` is called, the `Constants` is loaded and `SomeClass` is loaded.

If your agent `Inst` requires `Constants`, then `Constants` should be loaded before `Main`.

The fun part is that if you have a cycle in dependencies, then the loop will be broken when it is detected, and the result will depend on the class loading order.

EDIT:
You can put the code above in files and run it with `java -verbose:class Main` and you would see a lot of classes loaded, including the sequence of your classes being loaded:

```
C:\temp\java>\opt\jdk-11\bin\java.exe -verbose:class Main
[0.009s][info][class,load] opened: C:\opt\jdk-11\lib\modules
.
.
.
[0.326s][info][class,load] Main source: file:/C:/temp/java/
[0.326s][info][class,load] java.lang.NamedPackage source: jrt:/java.base
[0.327s][info][class,load] java.lang.PublicMethods$MethodList source: jrt:/java.base
[0.327s][info][class,load] java.lang.PublicMethods$Key source: jrt:/java.base
[0.328s][info][class,load] java.lang.Void source: jrt:/java.base
[0.329s][info][class,load] Constants source: file:/C:/temp/java/
[0.330s][info][class,load] SomeClass source: file:/C:/temp/java/
[0.331s][info][class,load] jdk.internal.misc.TerminatingThreadLocal$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.331s][info][class,load] java.lang.Shutdown source: jrt:/java.base
[0.332s][info][class,load] java.lang.Shutdown$Lock source: jrt:/java.base
```

Comment: Small nitpick: Agents are loaded through the system class loader, which also loads the main method. See the [javadoc for the java.lang.instrument package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) (search for `appendToClassPathForInstrumentation`)

Comment: Ah! `But classes are loaded before these are needed.` This was the critical part that I was seemingly not seeing. So the execution graph of the application in the original example would then be (taking into mind Johannes' input): `Inst loaded -> premain() called -> Main loaded -> Constants loaded -> Constants static initializations -> SomeClass loaded -> SomeClass static initializations -> main() called`, having in mind that a different `classloader` may take over after `main()` is called. Notwithstanding scenario `3`, is this correct?

Comment: Actually: re-reading Johannes' comment regarding *constant expressions*, there would be no `Constants static initialization` part.

Comment: @user991710 Now that you put final in the `Constants.MAX_LENGTH` then it is inlined and the static initializer is not called. The best approach is to try it out, run with the command option `-verbose:class` , add `System.out.println()` and see what actually happens, because *small changes can have radical impact*